# How to use custom component in redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

In my redux-form app I have a Field that should be a custom component:

```
import Name from './NameComponent'
..

<Field
            name="boer"
            component={Name}
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"
/>
```

The component is NameComponent:

```
import React from 'react'
const Name= field => <div><input type="text">fill in here:</input></div>
export default Name;
```

When I run this CRA app I get this error, why? :

> ```
> Uncaught Invariant Violation: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of Name.
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
const Name = field => <input type="text" {...field.input} />
```

Also I encourage you to learn [this](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/field.md/#usage) and [this](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/field.md/#2-a-stateless-function) sections of Redux Form docs